# Spreadsheet get individual values and count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a list with dates, names and a value.
I am now looking for hours for a solution to list all individual names on a specific date and count them

so the list looks like:

```
Date    Name    Value
14.06.2021  Frank   1
14.06.2021  Frank   1
14.06.2021  Michael 1
14.06.2021  John    1
14.06.2021  Michael 1
15.06.2021  Frank   1
15.06.2021  Michael 1
15.06.2021  Michael 1
15.06.2021  Frank   1
15.06.2021  John    1
```

As Output for 14.06.2021 I want to get:

```
Frank   2
Michael 2
John    1
```

I tried with index, but don't get this working. Anybody an idea?

Here is a spreadsheet with the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YremoikrEcvTHMifVbF1CYv6yyDn_fKz_5z43SPauic/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: We can't access your spreadsheet. Please fix permissions.

Comment: Updated, I just made it like this, so everbody can duplicate to own version and not changing my one.. but now its changeable for everybody.

Comment: I would like to ask you to share the code in your question you are using to get data from a spreadsheet. So that we can know what logic you are trying and what programming language you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In I5 I entered

```
=query(A2:C; "Select B, sum(C) where A = date '"&TEXT(I1; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by B order by sum(C) desc label sum(C)''"; 0)
```

The formula references the date in cell I1. If you want to have the date part hard coded in the formula you can try

```
=query(A2:C; "Select B, sum(C) where A = date '2021-06-14' group by B order by sum(C) desc label sum(C)''"; 0)
```

Comment: perfect, awesome. now it is sorted by the number. how can it be sorted be the names, so A to Z?

Comment: I did it with: =query(A2:C; "Select B, sum(C) where A = date '"&TEXT(I1; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by B order by B asc label sum(C)''"; 0) based on your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

For count:

`=query({A:C};"select Col2,count(Col3) where Col1 = date '"&text(E2;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by Col2 order by Col2 label count(Col3) '' ";0)`

It gets the date from a cell (`E2`), but you can hard code it into the query if you need to, using:

`where Col1 = date '2021-06-14'`

For a sum of:

`=query({A:C};"select Col2,sum(Col3) where Col1 = date '"&text(E2;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by Col2 order by Col2 label sum(Col3) '' ";0)`

[image]

Comment: Wow, this works. But it seems not to update/change when I switch date to 15.06.2021. See: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bQ2P1VwQaHcpNU6MkHJOW31Psroqsk8tVx4pewaf0YI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Updated, using sum rather than count